# Delete directory

Tags: chown, rm

Sometimes I want to bang my head when it concerns understanding file permissions.

I want to delete a dir called Test_Dir.

andy is the owner. andy is in group.

No files in directory have immutable attribute.

When I try to delete it, I get
Operation not permitted.

I have tried

```
sudo chown -R andy Test_Dir
sudo rm -R Test_Dir
[sudo] password for andy: 
rm: cannot remove 'Test_Dir/Urges1.png': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'Test_Dir/Blank.odt': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'Test_Dir/old_file.txt': Operation not permitted
```

I created the directory, why can't I simple delete it?

I removed append attribute, so keep that in mind.

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 andy andy 4096 Aug 19 04:33 Test_Dir
total 1124
-rw-r--rw- 1 andy andy 1149776 Aug 12 08:04 Urges1.png

--------------e--- Test_Dir
--------------e--- Test_Dir/Urges1.png
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and append the ouput of `ls -l -d Test_Dir; ls -l Test_Dir` so we can see the actual permissions?

Comment: Btw: your mentioning of the _immutable_ attribute suggests you are fiddling around with `chattr` and/or `lsattr`. Only in very rare cases you would do that. It's probably best to forget about these two commands as `chmod` and `chown`/`chgrp` will almost always be sufficient.

Comment: … and while you are at it, please also include the output of `lsattr -d Test_Dir; lsattr Test_Dir`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Made your recommended changes.

Comment: Where is your directory? ie `~/Test_Dir` or `/Test_Dir`? Some comments are recommending using `sudo` because it's not in home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Delete everything. The rm command has a powerful option, -R (or -r ), otherwise known as the recursive option. When you run the rm -R command on a folder, you're telling Terminal to delete that folder, any files it contains, any sub-folders it contains, and any files or folders in those sub-folders, all the way down and and -f forces it to (so that it wont stop, asking you if you want to delete the file)

As this appears not to be your home directory, you will need to prepend sudo

Comment: _"My `-f` switch is way more powerful than your `-r` switch!"_ Have you ever heard Yoda saying _"May the recursive be with you"_?

Comment: @PerlDuck thanks for the reminder about -f switch.

Comment: LOL. The more I read this question and its answers the more I think the OP did something with `chattr` that prevents the directory and/or files to be removed, even if the permissions and ownership as reported by `ls -l` _seem_ to be fit.

Comment: @PerlDuck looking at some of his earlier questions, the OP does seem to go where others fear to tread...

Comment: Might be. :-) I believe he's a curious beginner and simply tries out all the things and commands he encounters. That's not bad and in fact I like that approach.

Comment: @Graham You are right. I love learning and you can't make an omelet without breaking some eggs.

Comment: @fixit7 You need to break all the eggs to make an omelet without getting the shells stuck between your teeth! I'd suggest you have a vanilla Ubuntu test bed and a separate system which you can 'break' at will... bonne chance

Comment: @Graham Merci. That's one idea. Clonezilla is also another good one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to remove the directory and all its contents:

```
sudo rm -Rf Test_Dir
```

Using the `R` option sets `rm` to run recursively, and the `f` option forces deletion.